# Am I wrong to assume the <details> element is not a block level element?

Tags: css, html

I want to know for sure if `<details>` is a block level element. The reason I ask is because:

1. MDN has a "complete" [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) for all block level elements and `<details>` is not on the list.
2. The [W3C spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-details-element.html) on this element has no mention of it being a block level element
3. Same as #2 but for the MDN [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)
4. Same as #2 for the [W3C HTML5 elements spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#elements-0)

and

5. The spec in #3 has a Codepen for `<details>`. When you open this Codepen in Firefox (54.0.1) and Inspect the `<details>` element, it is `inline` but when you open the same Codepen in Chrome (59.0.3071) the same element is set as `block` by the User Agent Stylesheet.

*Is the `<details>` element inline or block, or does it depend on the browser?*

Comment: From the tooltip for this tag: Don't use this tag. It is ambiguous, and too broad to be meaningful.

Comment: @Mickers, thanks but I need a definitive answer because users at my workplace are using details under the assumption it is block level

Comment: Well, MDN also has a list of inline elements, and `details` is not on there either...

Comment: You can force it to e block or inline if you just want to be sure of how it's rendered in html... but i guess your question is not about that ? not sure if this element has a future as it's a but confusing.

Comment: Additional information to see which kind of tag it is
http://madebymike.github.io/html5-periodic-table/

Comment: I don't think you can say for certain based on #5 above and MDN not listing it as inline either.

Comment: Aside: MDN includes "canvas", "video"  and "output" in its list of block-level elements. All browsers have all three elements as `display:inline` by default.

Comment: ... and how it manages to include "tfoot" but not "thead" and "tbody" is anybody's guess.

Comment: @Alohci, do you know of a definitive source for block level elements?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob - There's no such thing. A block-level element was an HTML4 and earlier concept, and does not exist at all in HTML5. Block-level-ness is now a CSS concept only, and means that its [`display-outside`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#outer-role) setting is "block". The HTML5 spec [Rendering section](http://w3c.github.io/html/rendering.html#rendering) provides suggestions for browser's expected default CSS settings but browsers do not have to follow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<details>` element behaves as a block level element.  To test this, I opened a jsfiddle, added a `<details>` element and inspected it.  I was also able to set it to inline just fine.

The current version of Microsoft Edge does not support this element so I would not recommend its use in a production environment.

EDIT: I forgot to comment on your Firefox observation, my version of Firefox is up-to-date and also displays it as a block element.

Comment: The Codepen on FF displays it as inline - perhaps an artifact of Codepen?

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned I used jsfiddle.  I'll check it out with codepen and firefox.

Comment: Actually 'inline' might not mean css inline on FF under the Rules tab - I clicked 'inline' and am shown source code. Also <p> shown as inline. Not sure...maybe I should disregard this

Comment: Shows up full-width on mine.  My version of Firefox is 54.0.1 just like your's.  Says I'm using the 32-bit version.  Can't imagine that makes a difference, I don't have any extensions on my Firefox either.

Comment: Hey, I see what you're saying now.  My FireFox does say inline, but up in the top-right corner of the stylesheet.  If I change it to display:block, it doesn't update that, so I have no idea what that is indicating.  It is acting like a block element either way.

Comment: Okay cool.  You were right in your previous comment when you realized "inline" might not mean css inline.  It's referring to the "inline style" you're adding in the inspector.  So, styles coming from a source say something like "style.css:36" a style you've added inside the inspector simply says "inline".

Answer (score 1):

Upon something like this:

```
<span><details></details></span>
```

... the W3C HTML Validator says:

> Element [details](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-details-element) not allowed as child of element [span](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-span-element) in this context.
>
> Contexts in which element [details](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-details-element) may be used:
>         Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#flow-content-2) is expected.
>   Content model for element [span](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-span-element):
>         [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#phrasing-content-2).

If you follow the links for both content types you'll find two different tag lists and many tags belong to *both*.

I suspect that block/inline difference was a key concept in the early days of HTML but it's no longer relevant. Neither HTML5 nor CSS3 are defined in terms where an element must unequivocally match one of those categories.